# RTK query is executed AFTER the result status goes from 'pending' to 'uninitialized'

Tags: rtk-query

Upon initial execution, the sequence of events is as expected:

1. Status is 'pending'
2. Query is executed
3. Status is 'fulfilled'
4. Status is 'uninitialized'

[image]

However, with subsequent executions, the sequence of events changes as follows:

1. Status is 'pending'
2. Status is 'uninitialized'
3. Query is executed

[image]

Can anyone explain this strange behavior?

Update: I observed another strange occurrence -- isFetching and isSuccess are both true
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't go back to `isUninitialized`, ever. If you can, please create a small reproduction and file an issue.

Comment: I'm using @reduxjs/toolkit 1.8.1. Maybe trying the latest version would help?

Comment: Same issue with the latest version

Comment: I will attempt to create a demo and file an issue when time allows. In the mean time, please see my update in the original description. Is it normal for `isFetching` and `isSuccess` to be true at the same time?

Comment: Yes, that's normal if you switch from one value that loaded successfully to another one that is still loading. Thank you for filing an issue!

Comment: Is checking `isSuccess && !isFetching` the most reliable way to determine whether the query was executed?

Comment: Probably - although most of the time it shouldn't matter too much - the hooks are meant to be used declaratively. Are you trying to base some kind of side effect on this?

Comment: Yes. I'm using the results of the query in my useEffect hook and also setting the state variable which triggers the query in the first place to false so it doesn't run again until the variable is set to true via a button click handler.

Comment: You don't need to set that variable. That query won't run again unless you explicitly run something like `refresh`, or change the input argument to your `useMyQuery` hook. What else are you doing in that effect?

Comment: I think I still need the variable because the component contains a form with numerous inputs whose values are passed to the query as parameters. I don't want the query to run every time an individual input value changes but rather only when a button is clicked. Aside from that,  I'm also setting a state variable to notify the user if the query didn't return any results.

Comment: That "no results" state variable can be derived during render though - it doesn't need state?
For the other thing, yes, you might need a variable, but it wouldn't need to be "reset" after a query. Also, could this maybe better be a mutation?

Comment: Perhaps state isn't needed for the "no results" thing, but I think it still requires checking `isFetching` and `isSuccess` to determine whether the absence of data is due to the query's not having executed yet or not having returned any results. As for using a mutation instead of a query, I actually have thought about it and even resorted to doing that at times when I just couldn't figure out a good way to trigger the query. However, I was under the impression that mutations aren't cached like queries, since they don't offer tags. Maybe I'm misunderstanding mutations?

Comment: Yeah you're right, those are not cached. You could also look into a lazy query. For the rest, I think I maybe just don't get what your actual intention with "absence of data" here is.